# Feeling dumb in Visual Studio Code- Can't load img or font from my files to my CSS sheet

Tags: css, image, fonts

Clearly I am doing something wrong (FYI totally new). I tried using fonts loaded on my computer for my CSS stylesheet (font file in my VSC) Nope. Tried using img for background from my files. Nope.

I have tried the following: (just as an example of the img option)
So I am trying to set my background for my < body > tag

With Relative Path: (copied from right click on the file and select "copy relative path"

```
body {
    background-image: url(img\tire background.jpg);
}
```

/* also done with various formatting to ensure it wasn't just lost somewhere or too large/small*/

```
body {
    background-image: url(..\img\tire background.jpg);
}  

body {
    background-image: url('..\img\tire background.jpg');
}  

body {
    background-image: url('img\tire background.jpg');
}
```

Also with the Full path: (same method, right click select "copy path")

```
body {
    background-image: url(C:\Users\BradJen\Desktop\Big Toyz Coding Project 1\big-toyz\img\tire background.jpg);
}
```

(with all the variations of quotes, formatting, etc)

It works when I source it from the web, or use in my HTML. Same with my fonts. I can do it from google fonts, but not ones in my folder. And oddly enough it worked one time, but the image disappeared after I placed an image over it in my HTML doc.

I have googled a bunch but being new, most of the technical explanations were over my head or didn't work with my issues. I know it is probably something incredibly simple and ridiculous. Thanks in advance anyone!

Comment: try to install this extension [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense)

Comment: Thanks for the edits as well. noted for future reference! I will give it a shot! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to escape the space in the file name. Also, the path you're looking for is relative to the *calling* `CSS`.

Say you have the following setup:

[image]

I'm linking to the `CSS` in `css/style.css` from my `index.html`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

I want to use `kitten image.jpg` (note the space in the file name) in `body`.

From `css/style.css`:

```css
body {
  background: url("../kitten\ image.jpg") 0 0 transparent no-repeat;
}
```

However, it's more typical to use dashes or underscores in this situation to avoid the need to escape spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the time to respond! I am assuming that means change the file name itself so there are no spaces. I attempted this renaming it as img\tirebackground.jpg. still nothing. SO I have now tried the above with the file name containing no spaces.

Comment: @fundiculous I've updated my answer and provided more details for you.

Comment: Got it! thanks so much for the help Andy! Much appreciated as I felt my head was about to explode.

Comment: @fundiculous Glad it helped. If you can select my answer as the chosen answer, I'd appreciate it.